# HTML5 banners not displayed in Admob campaigns (House ad / Direct sold)

Tags: html, admob, ads

Since the 20th of June 2019, our ads in **HTML5** are not displayed anymore **Admob** campaign while other ads (images/text) are displayed.

Two important things:
 - we did not change ANYTHING to our configuration. It just stopped working without any reason!
 - we know that HTML5 ads are only available for apps hosted outside of Play store and App store as said in [Admob Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6185487?hl=en&ref_topic=6162738).

**Did anyone face the same issue!?**

Comment: Hi, same issue here, did you solve this ? thanks !